# argondash don't work with horizontal layout

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Hi and thanks for reading me

I am working with a dashboard made with shiny, argondash and argonr, but I noticed that the horizontal layout does not work correctly, since the windows continue to be displayed vertically. Is there any way to correct this? I would expect it to look like this:

[image]

The code is the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(argonDash)
library(argonR)
shinyApp(
  ui = argonDashPage(title = 'Sync the City',
                     description = 'Testing',
                     header = argonDashHeader(color = 'primary', separator = TRUE),
                     sidebar = argonDashSidebar(vertical = FALSE,
                                                brand_logo = "https://elpacientecolombiano.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/LOGO-SALUD-MORADO.png",
                                                id = 'sidebar',
                                                argonSidebarHeader(title = 'Main Menu'),
                                                
                                                argonSidebarMenu(
                                                  argonSidebarItem(tabName = 'landing_page', 'Landing Page'),
                                                  argonSidebarItem(tabName = 'map', 'Map'),
                                                  argonSidebarItem(tabName = 'network', 'Network')
                                                )
                     )
  ),
  server = function(input, output){}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the following arguments to your code :

- `size = "md"` in `argonDashSidebar()`
- `style = "display:-webkit-inline-box;"` in `argonSidebarMenu()`

  ```
  library(shiny)
  library(argonDash)
  library(argonR)
  shinyApp(
   ui = argonDashPage(
     title = 'Sync the City',
     description = 'Testing',
     header = argonDashHeader(color = 'primary', separator = TRUE),
     sidebar = argonDashSidebar(
       vertical = FALSE,
       brand_logo = "https://elpacientecolombiano.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/LOGO-SALUD-MORADO.png",
       id = 'sidebar',
       size = "md",
       argonSidebarHeader(title = 'Main Menu'),
       argonSidebarMenu(
         style = "display:-webkit-inline-box;",
         argonSidebarItem(tabName = 'landing_page', 'Landing Page'),
         argonSidebarItem(tabName = 'map', 'Map'),
         argonSidebarItem(tabName = 'network', 'Network')
         )
       ) 
     ),
   server = function(input, output){}
  )
  ```

Comment: Any idea to switch between horizontal and vertical dependend on media size?

Comment: Ask a new question to the community Roman :)